# Does http and https will share the same sessions

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-state, session-variables

I am building a web application and I need to know whether I can share the Same session or not between http or https?

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. Most website login mechanisms do it. They transfer password in cleartext over secure HTTPS, and after authenticated, they redirect you back to fast HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, Sessions are shared across Http and Https requests.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? (I believe you, I just like to see these things written somewhere official.)